# What should be a container component connected with a redux store and what should not be?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Is there any guideline for what component should be a container component connected with a redux store and what component should not be?

Probably, I should ask what kind of state needs to be an application-level state and what kind of state needs to be an component-level state.

I don't have any guideline for this yet personally, but I think these states are the candidate for an application-level state.

1. a state which is shared by multiple components.
2. hmm... that's it, isn't it?

So, back to my original question, any components that have a state shared by multiple components are the good candidate for a container component connected with a redux store?

Comment: Well, any component that needs to access the global state should be connected. Ones that don't depend on global state don't need to be connected.

Comment: Thanks! So,,, in general, a global state is something that are being accessed by multiple components or something else, right? If a certain state is only accessed by a component, the state should not be the global state?

Comment: Yes multiple components can access the same global state. If state is internal and specific to one component, for example an input value, then it shouldn't be global state

Comment: I disagree with Andrew. First of all I don't like the notion of "global state", I understand we're talking about state in a Redux store here. You can have multiple stores and there's no reason not to create one per functional part of the page (top level component or other). Secondly, in my opinion all state should go to redux store. It's hard for me to imagine an input being internal state of a component and not ever affecting the rest of the app. Having all state in Redux allows you for example to reload page  or let users navigate and the app bevahing as expected.

Comment: @MikeSzyndel, whilst you can have multiple stores, I very rarely (if ever) recommend it.  The main reason is that when using `react-redux` only one store can be provided by the `Provider`, making accessing a bit of data from two or more the store incredibly difficult.

Comment: @Hayatomo, if the data is fetched from or sent to a remote back end, it is usually another good candidate for keeping it in the redux store. In my experience, the only state that shouldn't make it's way to the redux store is what I call "Presentational State". That is, state that only exists to help the presentation of components, e.g. the currently selected tab, the open state of an accordion, etc. To that end, I wrote a library, [react-purely-stateful](https://github.com/mpeyper/react-purely-stateful) that allows me to write presentational components that are backed by local state.

Answer (score 0):

Your components should ideally just render a UI based on props. So start with a functional component. If you need lifecycle hooks, you will, of course, need a class, but try not to do this with state.

To populate the props of your component, you need a container. This is a blackbox component which takes data and marshals into the props of your component. It can get data from redux, your API, graphql, or even using HOC's from recompose.